# NTP not supported

Tags: 20.04, ntp, timezone

In Ubuntu 20.04, I see that I can not change the `set-ntp` due to the following error.

```
# timedatectl set-ntp true
Failed to set ntp: NTP not supported
```

Any way to fix that?

UPDATE:

It seems that `systemd-timesyncd` fails with the start command.

```
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
● systemd-timesyncd.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit systemd-timesyncd.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
$ sudo systemctl start systemd-timesyncd
Failed to start systemd-timesyncd.service: Unit systemd-timesyncd.service is masked.
```

**Solution**

**Using the command `sudo timedatectl set-ntp yes` the problem is now fixed.**

Comment: What this would usually enable/disable is systemd-timesyncd (works fine for me in a new and clean Focal VM btw). You could try checking what this reports and add it to the question `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt: Please see the updated post.

Comment: In case you end up here with the issue (the message) on Amazon Linux. `timesyncd` [is not available](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=54021#p239216) there. Use [`chrony`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html#configure-amazon-time-service-amazon-linux) or something.

Answer (score 50):

This worked for me on Ubuntu:

Install NTP:

```
apt install systemd-timesyncd
```

Activate NTP:

```
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

Comment: The OP indicates that systemd-timesyncd is already installed, but configured not to start.  This will not do anything useful to solve the problem.

Comment: @PaulGear My system didn't have systemd-timesyncd but behaved just as OP indicated. OP has not stated that it is already installed. As it stands, this answer has solved my issue. I fail to understand why `systemd-timesyncd` is recognized as masked when the package is not installed.

Comment: ... and let me say thanks and comment that a Raspberry Pi installed with Raspbian 11 bullseye solved its issues by following your steps :) Just in case somebody in the future ends up here with Raspberry Pi issues

Comment: this just helped us as well, I think this one should be the accepted answer here

Comment: +1 This also works on raspberry pi

Answer (score 17):

Your `systemd-timesyncd` service is *masked*.  That means it can't be started, and can't be enabled.  To reverse this, you need to run the following:

```
systemctl unmask systemd-timesyncd.service
```

Then you can enable and start the service:

```
systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd.service
systemctl start systemd-timesyncd.service
```

**HOWEVER**, it's pretty unlikely that your system got into this state on its own.  Perhaps you followed some instructions to enable a more full-featured NTP server, like `chronyd` or `ntpd`?  I recommend double-checking that they aren't installed before you proceed with the above method:

```
systemctl status chronyd.service
systemctl status ntp.service
```

If either of the above commands returns a good status, I recommend that you leave `systemd-timesyncd` disabled and masked.